# How do I add a list of ssl certificates to a list of of alb listeners I have created using one of the Terraform for loop contstructs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**On AWS, using Terraform it has become possible to add multiple ssl certificates to ALB listerners. I can do this by creating a listener resource and creating multiple aws_lb_listener_certificate resources.**

**So something like this works fine:**

```
 resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb_listener" {  
      load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.alb.arn  
      port              = 443  
      protocol          = "HTTPS"
      default_action {    
          target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn
          type = lookup(var.alb_listener, "action")  
       }
  } 

resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "testme_ssl_cert" {
  listener_arn    = "${aws_alb_listener.alb_listener.arn}"
  certificate_arn = "${data.aws_acm_certificate.testme.arn}" 
}
```

**But I am trying to reduce the amount of code I am using to do this by building my listeners from config. So I can build my listeners from a map variable like this. And that works fine.**

```
    resource "aws_lb_listener" "encrypted_listener" {
      load_balancer_arn       = aws_alb.alb.arn
      for_each = var.ssl_forwarding
          port                = each.key
          protocol            = each.value
          certificate_arn = lookup(var.default_certificate,each.key)
          default_action {
            target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn
            type             = "forward"
          }   
    }

    variable "ssl_forwarding" {
        default = { 
            443 =   "HTTPS"
            8081 =   "HTTPS"         
      }
```

**Now I want to add the rest of the certificates to the listeners I have just created.**

```
So I need something that looks like this (I think):

    variable "additional_certificates" {
        default=[
            "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-3ba688bab27a", #cert 1
            "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-4fa688deb27a", #cert 2
        ]
    }

    resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "ssl_certs" 
            listener_arn    = //for every listener that I just created
            certificate_arn = //add every certificate in additional_certificates
    }
```

**I don't understand how to deal with the multiplicy of the listeners. The multiplicity of the certificates. And finally the multiplicity of the certiticates with the multiplicity of the listeners.**

***All suggestions on how to attack this problem appreciated. Suggestions of work arounds apprecited too. Thanks.....*

Update:
Thanks foranswer from Marcin... but that only allows me add to add one extra SSL cer.
I think var is going to look like this... so I can add n certificates to n load balancers.

```
variable "additional_certificates" {
     default = { 
       443 = ["arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect1",
              "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect2"
              ""arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect....n" //could be any number of certs here                                                                                                                      
             ]
       8081 = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-4fa688deb27a"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your `aws_lb_listener.encrypted_listener` is valid and it works, as its not specified otherwise in the question. ALso it would be better if `additional_certificates` was a map, as you are using map for `ssl_forwarding`. Thus, your `ssl_certs` could be:

```
variable "additional_certificates" {
     default = {
       443 = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-3ba688bab27a",
       8081 = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-4fa688deb27a"
    }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "ssl_certs" {
    
    for_each =  aws_lb_listener.encrypted_listener

    listener_arn    = each.value.arn
    certificate_arn = var.additional_certificates[each.key]
}
```

**Update**

If you can have random number of ports with random number of certs, I can propose the following:

```
variable "additional_certificates" {

   default = { 
     443 = ["arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect1",
            "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect2",
            "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect....n"
           ]
     8081 = ["arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-4fa688deb27a"]
     
     9999 = ["arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-223332",
             "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-22222"]
  }
}


locals {
  # flatten the additional_certificates
  additional_certificates_flat = merge([
      for port, certs in var.additional_certificates:
        {for cert in certs: 
          "${port}-${cert}" => {"port" = port, "cert" = cert}
        }
  ]...)

}
```

The `var.additional_certificates` flattened into `local.additional_certificates_flat` will be:

```
{
  "443-arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect....n" = {
    "cert" = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect....n"
    "port" = "443"
  }
  "443-arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect1" = {
    "cert" = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect1"
    "port" = "443"
  }
  "443-arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect2" = {
    "cert" = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect2"
    "port" = "443"
  }
  "8081-arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-4fa688deb27a" = {
    "cert" = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-4fa688deb27a"
    "port" = "8081"
  }
  "9999-arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-22222" = {
    "cert" = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-22222"
    "port" = "9999"
  }
  "9999-arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-223332" = {
    "cert" = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-223332"
    "port" = "9999"
  }
}
```

Then,

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "ssl_certs" {
    
    for_each =  local.additional_certificates_flat

    listener_arn    = aws_lb_listener.encrypted_listener[each.value.port].arn
    certificate_arn = each.value.cert
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply that solves part of the problem. This only adds a second certificate. Where I was hoping to add n. So if using a map it would be like this.......
{
 443 = ["arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect1",
              "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect2"
              ""arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blah_ect....n" //could be any number of certs here                                                                                                                      
             ]
       8081 = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:blah_blach_ect-4fa688deb27a"
}

Comment: @DarrenWhite In this case it would be better to split it into two `aws_lb_listener_certificate` resources, one for 443 and second for 8081. Two resources would be much easier to read, write, debug and maintain then coming out with some convoluted looping mechanisms. Have you considered that?

Comment: Thank. I have considered this. Those are just example ports... I could have 100 of them. Or n of them. I won't know ahead of time. So I need 'n' ports. With 'n' certificates. The idea here is to solve this so I don't need to know ahead of time how many certs or ports I need.

Comment: @DarrenWhite Are these certs unique, i.e. there won't be common certs between ports?

Comment: Yes, that is right. The certs are unique between the ports.

Comment: @DarrenWhite Its ok. I updated an answer which should work for non-unique case as well. Please have a look. Also, I haven't run aws_lb_listener_certificate.ssl_certs as I don't have multiple certs and listeners, so some adjustment may still be required.

Comment: @DarrenWhite How did it go? Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I can see how this should work but when the merge function in the local declarion is called it gives me an error "Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple". I tried to use flatten instead, which makes the local variable declaration work, but then causes me a similar problem when I decare the resource. Does var.additional.certificates have to be a map?

Comment: @DarrenWhite Are you sure you didn't forget about `...` when doing merge?

Comment: Of course I did ... thanks for all you help. I'm sure this answer is going to help a lot of other people.